# Django CMS multilingual and international supports based on country or region

Tags: python, django-models, translation, multilingual, django-cms

I am looking out for solution for one scenario in project.

I would like to use following technologies / tools

```
Django 1.6.x stable or 1.7
mysql
django-cms / mezzanine / feincms
```

### ***SCENARIO***

CMS for Tourist Hotel Menu card.

I would like to add pages in CMS based on country and multiple languages

> **Example 1:**
>
> Country - India (IN)
>
> *primary* Language 1 - Dutch - Belgium (de) OFFER PAGE = 2 Belgium dishes are free
>
> Language 2 - Chinese - Singapore (zh) OFFER PAGE = 4 Chinese dishes are free
>
> ***Possible url for page***
>
> http://example.com/in/de/offer For India in Dutch OFFER PAGE = 2 Belgium dishes are free
>
> http://example.com/in/zh/offer For India in Chinese OFFER PAGE = 4 Chinese dishes are free
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Country - Singapore (SG)
>
> *primary* Language 1 - Thai - Thailand (th) OFFER PAGE = 7 thai dishes are free
>
> Language 2 - Ukrainian - Ukraine (uk) OFFER PAGE = 4 Ukrainian dishes are free
>
> Language 3 - Portuguese - Portugal (pt) OFFER PAGE = 5 Portuguese dishes are free
>
> ***Possible url for page***
>
> http://example.com/sg/th/offer For Singapore in Thai OFFER PAGE = 7 thai dishes are free
>
> http://example.com/sg/uk/offer For Singapore in Ukrainian OFFER PAGE = 4 Ukrainian dishes are free
>
> http://example.com/sg/pt/offer For Singapore in Portuguese OFFER PAGE = 5 Portuguese dishes are free

So my website need to support 15 countries and 3 languages, (for one page there will be *45* entries)
When admin add any page to CMS, he choose english as primary language and add the page with 45 possible combination.
Latter he will edit other pages according and publish them.
if page is not publish for the country, then user will get redirected to error page.

**NOTE**
For now, I need to manage the content of page not the url.

---

I went through the following the django plugins

> django-cms / mezzanine / feincms
>   Each one has multilingual and international supports using https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/django-cms/
>   and some model translation
>   https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-translation/

But I am not able to come up with conclusion, how do I implement above scenerio with available cms plugin?
I would like to go with *mezzanine*.

Do I need to build my own django package?
Is there any way to customise any of the following cms plugin and add multilingual and international support with country?

> django-cms / mezzanine / feincms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be biased, but I think you should use django CMS. It supports multi-site (I *think* you require this?), full i18n and it even offers plugins for country-based segmentation on top of all the internationalisation. (So, you could make country-based offers, regardless of the language used on the request).

Here's some videos on the topics by yours truly:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbNxojMo86v42AOM47uhaEFHIJFUM4d6M

In particular, you'll want to watch the one on personalization and segmentation (if that is what you'll require, not really clear in the question).

Comment: thanks. I have go through the required videos, but it seem partially it fulfils the my requirement. But I need to deal with whole page content not specific part of the page section, like each language can have totally different content from the other languages for the same page for country or specific region.

Comment: In django CMS, each language-specific version of a page can have entirely separate content if you so desire. Not an issue at all.

Comment: yeah that is true, but as mentioned in question `So my website need to support 15 countries and 3 languages, (for one page there will be 45 entries)`, I want to handle page content for each country and its supported language. so I want either 15 countries on top of 3 languages or 3 languages on top of 15 countries

Comment: Super. Sounds like CMS will have you covered then.

Comment: Django-CMS can do what you need. If you need those particular URL schemes /CC/LC/... then, you may have to write some custom middleware (not too complicated), but in general, django-CMS can handle multiple languages and you could address the multiple countries support via "multi-site" or the above-mentioned custom middleware.